# How to keep an important column value in a GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, group-by

Here is the example data set i have :

```
id | messageread | timestamp
 1 |       'yes' |       999
 1 |       'yes' |         0
 1 |        'no' |         0
```

I'm doing so :

```
SELECT *
FROM nvm
GROUP BY id
```

You will note that the data set is already `ORDER BY timestamp DESC`

As it should, MySQL is returning the first row.

What i'd want is MySQL to return the first row, but with `messageread='no'` IF `messageread='no'` in one of the grouped rows, no matter if the *normally* returned row is `'yes'` or `'no'`

Is that possible with MySQL? I promised myself to do as much as possible with MySQL and not PHP :-) Thanks!

Comment: Your "As it should" is not guaranteed. [The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html)

Comment: "As it usually does" if you prefer, but that's not the point. Thanks for pointing it out anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make sure all rows are from the same column do:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 t1 
LEFT JOIN table1 t2 ON ((t1.messageread, t1.id) < (t2.messageread, t2.id))
WHERE T2.ID IS NULL
```

This will select the minimum or maximum row from table1. And all columns will be from the same row.
If it doesn't work you need to change the `<` to a `>` it's late here and I cannot test the query, but it should do the job.

**Warning, antipattern ahead**
This has the smell of rotten eggs all over it, but if you want to mix and match fast do:

```
SELECT id, min(messageread), timestamp as random_timestamp
FROM table1
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: "all columns will be from the same row" you sumed it up, that's not what i'm looking for :/ It's already returning all columns from a same row, and this row is the good one. I just want one column to take a particular value no matter the colmun's value of the selected row, IF this value is encountered in any other row. @Dave made a good proposition, but too heavy to use in my case, i'm looking for something simpler

Comment: And i love it, GOD BLESS ROTTEN EGGS! If there's any cleaner way of doing so, i'm all listening, but that'll do until then. Thanks, dear savior !

Comment: @Pioul, the cleaner way is the first query. The fact that you are using duplicate `id`'s is a code smell in itself. id is supposed to be the PK.

Comment: Actually like i said in a comment on the previous answer, it's a loong query, and there is no "physical" column containing those values, i'm just creating and returning them to a parent `SELECT` based on multiple conditions, so the first query won't work

Comment: If your `looong query` returns duplicate id's than you've written that query wrong. I suggest asking a question about that so it can be fixed. It will probably also speed that query up.

Comment: Actually it's `loooong query`, you forgot an 'o'. I hope that explains everything. (Seriously, this query is a masterpiece, it's unique and can't be touched.)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to do a CASE statement along with ANY.

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN 'no' = ANY(SELECT messageread FROM nvm t2 WHEN t2.id = t1.id)
        THEN 'no'
        ELSE 'yes'
        AS messageread,
    timestamp,
FROM nvm t1
GROUP BY t1.id
```

Note: you're basically getting a random timestamp here, do you want MAX(timestamp) or something?

Comment: The problem here is that `messageread` is determined after a 22 lines long SQL query, and your solution implies to run it twice (if i got it right). There isn't any "magic" keyword that will tell MySQL, when grouping, to keep a value for a column if it encounters it ? (Thanks anyway for the answer, and for the timestamp issue, i put it that way for the sake of simplicity but it's taken care of in the real query)

Comment: Not 100% sure, but you may wish to try returning true and false or 1 and 0 instead of no and yes, and then use a BIT_AND (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_bit-and).  So you'd `SELECT BIT_AND(messageread) as messageread`

Comment: 'yes' and 'no' were meant to make it simpler in the post, but i'm really working with strings here, so i guess that won't work :/

Comment: Maybe you could do `BIT_AND(CASE WHEN 'no' THEN 0 ELSE 1)`?